# Asking about job location

Tags: negotiation, relocation, location

I am soon to be college grad this May. I have received a very good job offer from a very respected company as a part of a rotational program. The only problem I have is that the offer is for the one location (out of 6 that they are hiring for) that I did not want.

I was wondering if it is unprofessional to express that the location is not favorable and ask to be considered for the other locations if the offers that they extended in those locations are turned down. When I applied for the job, I did not apply for a specific location, but instead they placed you after the interview process. As far as I know the roles are very similar in each of the locations and everyone who is being considered for these roles are also going to be fresh out of college when starting.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think it is unprofessional at all to ask about it. You are entitled to inquire about details in the job offer, and given that applicants were given the location only after the interview process, you might not be the only one to ask about it.

Tell them that you're really interested in the job offer, but at the same time, give them all the reasons why the location is just unfavorable for you . Also, tell them your preferred location(s) so that they know where to look for open slots first.

You might end up getting a more favorable location, but you also have to consider how much of a factor the current location is to you accepting the job offer should the offer and location stay as it is.

Answer (score 3):

The company want you, and they want you to stay as long a possible. It is in their interests to have you happy, so I see no reason not to tell them.

You may be worrying that doing so may cause them to reject you totally if they can only offer that location. I do not think so.

It seems unlikely that they would turn you down for expressing preference. If they can only offer you that location, they will expect you to make an adult, informed decision as to whether you can work there or not.

If not, they expect you to tell them. If you accept the position, they expect to hear no more about your preference, which includes using a long commune as an excuse for lateness, amongst other things.

In my opinion, you have nothing to lose and everything to gain.

Answer (score 1):

Just because you apply for a job, go to the interviews, and are offered a job you don't have to accept it.

When you receive an imperfect offer, you can either accept the imperfection, negotiate the offer, or reject the offer. With the negotiation option you have to decide how aggressive you will be. Too aggressive for a minor point could make it easy for them to reject you.

But If you truly don't want to work at that location, and the other terms of the offer don't change your mind. Then your option is reject or negotiate. So you should negotiate. If that negotiation fails, then reject.

Up until you sign and return a offer without conditions keep looking, applying and interviewing.